# How to isolate a list of URIs in a RDF file using CONSTRUCT or DESCRIBE in SPARQL?

Tags: select, sparql, rdf

I'm trying to get only a list of URIs in RDF instead of a list of triples:

```
PREFIX gr: <http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>

DESCRIBE  ?product 
WHERE
{
  ?product rdfs:subClassOf gr:ProductOrService .
}
```

Using `SELECT`, instead of `DESCRIBE` I receive only the subject (which I want), but not as an RDF but like a SPARQL Result with binds, vars, etc.

Using `CONSTRUCT`, I can't specify only the `?product`, as above, so the closest I can get is:

```
PREFIX gr: <http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>

CONSTRUCT
WHERE
{
  ?product rdfs:subClassOf gr:ProductOrService .
}
```

Which returns an RDF with triples of different products, but the same properties and objects.

Comment: RDF is about triples. If you need RDF, you will receive triples (or even quads). Or do you want to receive `rdf:List` of URIs?

Comment: An rdf:List of URIs. That's what I meant!

Comment: I suggest you rewrite your question, and maybe give us a better idea of your end goals, as what you've described wanting doesn't make sense to at least 3 of us reading, commenting, and answering… As it stands, I think you may be working on an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you should read over [the SPARQL specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#QueryForms), which tells you that this is exactly as expected.  To get the single column you wish, you must use `SELECT`.

> SPARQL has four query forms. These query forms use the solutions from pattern matching to form result sets or RDF graphs. The query forms are:
>
> - `SELECT`
>        Returns all, or a subset of, the variables bound in a query pattern match.
> - `CONSTRUCT`
>        Returns an RDF graph constructed by substituting variables in a set of triple templates.
> - `ASK`
>        Returns a boolean indicating whether a query pattern matches or not.
> - `DESCRIBE`
>        Returns an RDF graph that describes the resources found.

Comment: I know it is exactly what I should expect. I am trying to figure out the workaround to have only the URIs as response without the variables bound.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. I've used SELECT, but instead of binds and vars, as output received a "Comma-Separated Values (with fields in N-Triples syntax)" CSV file:

```
<http://www.productontology.org/id/Real_estate>
<http://www.productontology.org/id/Automobile>
<http://www.productontology.org/id/Auction>
<http://www.productontology.org/id/Video_game>
<http://www.productontology.org/id/Campsite>
<http://www.productontology.org/id/Car>
<http://www.productontology.org/id/Audiobook>
<http://www.productontology.org/id/Browser_game>
...
```

Comment: This does not give you what you said you wanted in the question (namely, an rdf:List containing the result URIs).

Comment: As @JeenBroekstra said, that's not an [`rdf:List`](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-schema/#ch_list). It's also not a [CSV](http://dbpedia.org/resource/Comma-separated_values) -- there are no commas. The field you show here is not in "N-Triples syntax" (because there are no triples), but is simply a column of [URIs](http://dbpedia.org/resource/Uniform_Resource_Identifier) (as opposed to [CURIEs](http://dbpedia.org/resource/CURIE)).

Comment: Given this self-answer, I think your original question really amounts to "how do I use the (unnamed) tool I'm using, to get a plain-text list of URIs that satisfy my query, instead of an RDF serialization of any form?"

Answer (score 1):

Representing the result of a SPARQL SELECT query as an RDF List is a tooling issue - it is not something that can be solved in SPARQL in general.

Some SPARQL tools may have ways to support rendering the query result as an RDF list. But it's not something you can fix by just formulating your query differently, you'll need to use a tool to (programmatically) format the result.

In Java, using Eclipse RDF4J, you can do it as follows (untested so you may need to tweak it to work properly, but it should give you a general idea):

```java
String query = "SELECT ?product WHERE {  ?product rdfs:subClassOf gr:ProductOrService . }";

// do the query on repo and convert to a Java list of URI objects     
List<URI> results = Repositories.tupleQuery(
  repo, 
  query, 
  r -> QueryResults.stream(r).map(bs -> (URI)bs.getValue("product")).collect(Collectors.toList()
);

// create a resource (bnode or URI) for the start of the rdf:List
Resource head = SimpleValueFactory.getInstance().createBNode();

// convert the Java list of results to an rdf:list and add it 
// to a newly-created RDF Model
Model m = RDFCollections.asRDF(results, head, new LinkedHashModel());
```

Once you have your result as an RDF model you can use any of the existing [RDF4J APIs](http://docs.rdf4j.org/programming) to write it to file or to store it in a triplestore.

Now, I am not claiming that any of this is a good idea - I have never seen a use case for something like this. But this is how I would do it if it were necessary.